# Missing checkmates in one

Tags: no-computers, chess, optimization, construction

Have you ever missed a one-move checkmate and immediately realized it after making your move? If you have, you just might have what it takes to crack this problem. Let's take an example:

> 1. g4 e5
> 2. f4 Be7?
> 3. Nc3 Nc6?
>
> [image]

In this example, black has already missed two mating moves: one with the queen (2...Qh4#), and one with the bishop (3...Bh4#). The goal is to find the **smallest number of moves** after which the same side has missed a mate-in-one with both a **queen**, a **rook**, a **knight**, a **bishop** and a **pawn**. Whoever finds the smallest number of moves wins.

Rules/clarifications:

> - The piece delivering checkmate is what counts. If you move a bishop to discover a mate by rook check, it's a mate by a rook. Mates by double-check are counted as both pieces.
> - Promoted pawns count as the promoted piece, not as a pawn.
> - You can use any moves from the starting position, not necessarily the same ones as in the example.

Comment: Do we have to start with the six moves you've provided?

Comment: Edited to clarify the rules.

Comment: I don't think "both" means what you think it means. :)

Comment: @Rubio Incontheivable!

Comment: I take this is "helpmate", so to speak?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. f3 e6 2. g4 a5 3. Kf2 a4 4. Ke3 Qe7 5. Kf4 Qb4+ 6. Ke5 a3

Comment: Very nice! So many ways to finish it off.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. f3   e6
>  2. g4   h5
>  3. Kf2  a5
>  4. gxh5 a4
>  5. Ke3  Rxh5
>  6. Ke4  Rh4+
>  7. Ke5  g6??